# Manage mapped memory (glMapBuffer) with std::vector

Tags: c++, opengl, vector

it occurred to me that it would be a good idea to manage a range of mapped memory (from glMapBuffer) with a std::vector.

```
// map data to ptr
T* dataPtr = (T*)glMapBuffer(this->target, access);

[... debug code ...]

// try to construct a std::vector from dataPtr
T* dataPtrLast = dataPtr + size;
mappedVector = new std::vector<T>(dataPtr, dataPtrLast);
```

the problem is that the memory range won't be used directly but it is copied into the vector.

My question would be: is it possible to make the vector just 'use' the mapped memory range. (and ideally throw exceptions on resize/reserve)
Or is there any other standard container that would accomplish this?

Kind Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and for good reason. This code would never work. For example, you could alter the MapBuffer and break the size/capacity values inside the vector. You could push into the vector and cause an access violation/segmentation fault. You could cause a resize, destroying the buffer. And, fundamentally, if it's already within a contiguous array, what's the benefit? You could roll a custom container for fixed length arrays, I guess.

Especially! if you already have a pair of pointers to act like iterators.

Comment: This seems spot on.  I can't think of anything to add, except to also wonder what exactly made you think it would be a good idea?  From what I understand, the C++ 98 spec doesn't even guarantee contiguous storage in a vector.  (Though recent proposed revisions do clarify that)

Comment: C++98 is a LONG time ago. C++03 guarantees contiguous storage in a vector. That standard is more than applicable.

Comment: Ok ... i see
just thought that it would be nice to have the clean interface of vector to work on the mapped memory range :/

Comment: @Florian: What keeps your from creating your own container which wraps a bunch of such storage? A `static_vector`, wrapping stack space, has been invented many times, you can use any of these as a starting point.